# Including dynamic json-ld tags in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following snippet in my show.html.erb

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "Person",
  "name": "<%= @person_name %>",
  "logo": "<%= @person_img_url %>",
  "membersOf":[
    {
    <%= @person_orgs.each do  |group| %>
        "@context": "http://schema.org",
        "@type": "Organization",
        "name": "<%= group[:name] %>"
        "logo": "<%= group[:img_url] %>",
        "url": "https://siftery.com/groups/<%= group[:handle] %>"
    <% end %>
     }
   ]

}
```

The output which I get `membersOf` is `[{}{}{}]`does not turn out to be an array instead a string with missing commas. How should I correct so that `membersOf` is `[{},{},{}]`

Answer (score 4):

Another way is to build the object in Ruby and convert to JSON. This has the benefit of safely escaping all the parameters and looking cleaner.

```rb
<script type="application/ld+json">
<%=
  {
    :@context => "https://schema.org",
    :@type => "Person",
    :name => @person_name,
    :logo => @person_img_url,
    :membersOf => @person_orgs.map do |group|
      {
        :@type => "Organization",
        :name => group[:name],
        :logo => group[:img_url],
        :url => "https://siftery.com/groups/#{group[:handle]}"
      }
    end
  }.to_json.html_safe
%>
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
%script{type: "application/ld+json"}
 :plain
  {
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "Person",
  "name": "<%= @person_name %>",
  "logo": "<%= @person_img_url %>",
  "membersOf":[
    {
    <%= @person_orgs.each do  |group| %>
        "@context": "http://schema.org",
        "@type": "Organization",
        "name": "<%= group[:name] %>"
        "logo": "<%= group[:img_url] %>",
        "url": "https://siftery.com/groups/<%= group[:handle] %>"
    <% end %>
     }
   ]
  }
```

Instead of using `:javascript` filter, http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#filters, I have used the `%script` tag which allows me to define its `type` by using the `attribute method` that defines the type as `application/ld+json`, http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#attribute-methods

The `:plain` filter, it does not parse the filtered text. This is useful for large blocks of text without HTML tags, when you don’t want lines starting with . or - to be parsed, see doc http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#plain-filter

Answer (score 0):

Use `.map` instead of each so that it will return you an array

and also move the `{}` curly braces inside the loop

```
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "Person",
  "name": "<%= @person_name %>",
  "logo": "<%= @person_img_url %>",
  "membersOf": <%= @person_orgs.map do  |group| %>
                  {
                    "@context": "http://schema.org",
                    "@type": "Organization",
                    "name": "<%= group[:name] %>"
                    "logo": "<%= group[:img_url] %>",
                    "url": "https://siftery.com/groups/<%= group[:handle] %>"
                  }
                <% end %>
}
```